# How do I avoid a SynchronizationLockException?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code, which I based off of the [Monitor class example on the msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw.aspx).

```
    private void WebRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (WebRefresh.Enabled)//Only call from button
    {
        if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(deployIsRunning))
        {

                refreshWebVersion();

                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(deployIsRunning);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You cannot refresh during a deploy");
    }
}
```

The code throws [SynchronizationLockException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHTSYNCHRONIZATIONLOCK%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) on the Monitor.Exit() Call with an error message: "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." The error's explanation is that I tried to release a mutex that I did not own, but I can not enter the block of code where `Exit` is called unless `TryEnter` is successful.  How do I remove this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that `deployIsRunning` is a variable of type `bool` or some other value type. Your calls to `TryEnter` and `Exit` will box the value, creating a new object every time.

Basically, only ever use a reference type variable for a lock.